# Point out commented out code

Tags: git, version-control

I have some code which I'm going to refactor now. So I start refactoring the code and now big part of my code base, which I'm going to move is getting broken. I still want to be able to look into that code, since I'm going to refactor it, but it cannot be left in my code base, because it would be incompilable then.

I want to find an elegant way, how to keep the old code until the point it's all refactored.

I can think of several options:

- comment out the code
- delete it and look into `git` history every time I move the functionality
- some other way?

What is the most elegant approach in this?

Comment: Is there value in keeping the partially-refactored but not working code all compilable? Why not check it into a branch and work on it there until you're done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specific examples, it's hard to give a good answer.

But it's possible you're not refactoring, but rewriting. The definition of refactoring is

> "disciplined technique for restructuring an existing body of code,
>   altering its internal structure without changing its external
>   behavior"

Not changing its external behaviour means that any code that depends on the refactoring should continue to compile.

The Refactoring book by Martin Fowler provides plenty of examples of how to do this.

If, instead, you're rewriting, the most common solution is to use branches - keep your "old" code in one branch, and the new code in another.

Comment: you're right, it's rewriting

Answer (score 1):

Your answer it to use the other major version control feature - **[braches](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-1.html)** have a read in the link.  Then in your attempted refactored code directory you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
git branch my_refactored_code
```

This will allow you to have both working but messy code and refactoring under way code and to switch between them as necessary.